# Web page with different margin colors and centered content

Tags: css, html

I want to build a page where my content is centered but responsive - it should be of a maximum width of 960 pixels but diminish if the window size diminishes.
At the same time, I want to have the background of this page in different colors on its left and right margins.
How can I achieve that?
If I use margin:0 auto on my main div, I can't control the background any longer.

Answer (score 1):

For the content you will have

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

if you put in your css file

```
page { 
  width: 100%;
  background: #333; }

content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; }
```

for the background color you can try some trick like this (these will apply to content)

```
border-right: 10px solid #blue;
border-left: 10px solid #white;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make it have a `max-width` and a percent width, with margin auto on both sides.
If you want to have a multicolor body background you can position two boxes on the background and give each a different colour. Now position those on the background with a negative z-index for example, so that the rest stays on the viewport. Here, I made it for you:

**Source**: http://jsfiddle.net/p8ZNz/4/

**View fullscreen**: http://jsfiddle.net/p8ZNz/4/embedded/result/

**CSS**:

```
#left{
width:50%;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color:red;
z-index:-1;
}   
#right{
width:50%;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:50%;
background-color:blue;
z-index:-1;
}
#content{
position:relative;
width:90%;
height:100px;
max-width:960px;
margin:0px auto;
background-color:green;
color:#FFF;
}
```

The background will remain 50%-50% for all widths, and the centered box will grew up if you resize the window, till it reaches 960px wide. if you want the background be complete, just give it a 100% height!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/Sw9ae/

HTML

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="centered">centered</div>
```

CSS

```
.left,.right {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.left {
    left: 0;
    background: blue;
}
.right {
    right: 0;
    background: red;
}
.centered {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 400px;
    background: #ccc;
}​
```